# Java HashMap, get(key) method doesnt work

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm trying to create a `PhoneBook` class that uses a `HashMap` in Java.  When I add an entry using the `put()` method in `addContact()`, it works fine, but when I try to retrieve values in the `searchContact()` method, none are returned. I'm not getting null values; `HashMap` definitely contains the key(s) I am searching for, but the values associated with the key(s) are not being returned. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class PhoneBookContactsImpl {

    private Map<String, List<String>> contactMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public void addContact(String name, List<String> list) {        
        contactMap.put(name, list);
                //its working fine here
        System.out.println(contactMap.get(name));
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getContactMap() {

        Set set = contactMap.entrySet();
        Iterator i = contactMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : ");
            List<String> nos = (List<String>) me.getValue();
            System.out.println("Nos = " + nos + " n ");
            System.out.println(nos.size());
        }
        return contactMap;
    }

    public List<String> searchContact(String name) throws NoDataFoundException {

        if (contactMap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty PhoneBook");
            throw new NoDataFoundException();
        } else {
            if (contactMap.containsValue(name))
                return contactMap.get(name);              
                                 //it doesnt retrieve valur from here
            else {
                System.out.println("No Entry for Specified Entry");
                throw new NoDataFoundException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Every1, for helping me out, i had two problems one was, i used containsValue() insteas of containsKey() another problem the list variable in my main class, which i was passing as parameter, after passing i was calling Clear() method, so that emptied the other referenced links in PhoneBookContactsImpl.. Thank you every 1

Answer (score 3):

your if statement is checking if the phonebook has `name` as a value, so your get is never reached.

Try this:

```
if (contactMap.containsKey(name))
            return contactMap.get(name);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was one of my mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer points out you should be checking `containsKey` because `name` is a key, not a value. But why not make the whole thing much easier:

```
public List<String> searchContact(String name) throws NoDataFoundException {
    List<String> result = contactMap.get(name);
    if (result == null) { 
        // empty map, or no matching value or value is null
        throw new NoDataFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeaa with ur suggestion Method will be more easier, but i have to achieve two different case, one for no Entry for specified name, another for Blank ContactBook. thank u

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
if (contactMap.containsValue(name))
     return contactMap.get(name);
```

and you need to do:

```
if (contactMap.containsKey(name))
     return contactMap.get(name);
```